# Question about sets (Rings in probability theory)

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Let $\Omega$ be our sample space, we define a ring as $R\subset P(\Omega)$ verifying: $R\neq\emptyset$, $R$ is closed under finite intersections, and closed under symmetric difference.

Prove that $R$ is a ring iff $R$ is closed under finite intersections, finite unions and $\emptyset\in R$

My try:

$\Rightarrow$

We just need to show that $\emptyset\in R$ and $R$ is closed under finite unions.

Let $A\in R$ then $A\triangle A=\emptyset\in R$

Then $A\cup B = A\triangle (B\backslash A)\in R$

$\Leftarrow$

I'm struggling with this implication

(Let me know if the post title fits my problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, in general, not true. Let $\Omega=\{1,2,3\}$, $R=\{\emptyset,\{2\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$. Then you can see that $R$ is closed under finite union and finite intersection, and that $\emptyset\in R$.

$R$ is not, however, closed under symmetric difference: $\{1,2\}\triangle\{2,3\}=\{1,3\}\notin R$. So the reverse implication does not hold.

Instead, try proving  "$R$ is a ring if and only if $R$ is closed under finite union and taking relative complements ($A\backslash B$), and $R\neq\emptyset$".

Comment: Your "instead" it is not true in general. Take $\Omega $= {1,2,3} and $R=\{{\emptyset, \Omega, {1}, {2}, {1,2}\}$, R is a ring but it is not closed taking complements

Comment: @Iborra Thank you, I meant relative complements $A\backslash B$ for $A,B\in R$. Edited to reflect this.